# Creating a scatter behaviour in C#

Tags: c#

Hi I am practising my coding for my university course and I have built a virtual Aquarium.

I have currently got some sea horses in there and have made a chicken leg to appear when I click. I have written some code to say when the chicken leg appears they move vertically. However I want them to scatter and not go near the chicken leg or at least bump of it. my vertical swim behaviour code is:

```
` private void VerticalSwimBehaviour() //Verticle Swim scatter
    {
        Vector3 tokenPosition = this.PossessedToken.Position;
        tokenPosition.Y = tokenPosition.Y + mSpeed * mFacingDirection;

        if (tokenPosition.Y > 300 || tokenPosition.Y < -300) // Responds if fish goes to the top or bottom of screen
        {
            mFacingDirection = -mFacingDirection;
        }
        this.PossessedToken.Orientation = new Vector3(mFacingDirection, this.PossessedToken.Orientation.Y, this.PossessedToken.Orientation.X);
        this.PossessedToken.Position = tokenPosition;
    }
    private void RandomNumberMethod()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber1 = random.Next(1, 5);
        int randomNumber2 = random.Next(1, 150);
    }`
```

I want to make a behaviour that work like this but runs from the chicken leg.

here is my leg calling upon the behaviour when chicken leg appears

```
public override void Update(ref GameTime pGameTime)
    {
        Vector3 tokenPosition = this.PossessedToken.Position;
        HorizontalSwimBehaviour();
        velocidadMax();

        if (mAquarium.ChickenLeg != null)
        {
            VerticalSwimBehaviour();
        }



    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's the strangest setup to a question I've seen...

Comment: Your random number method is a bad idea; creating a new Random object seeds according to the current time, and you could be creating many within the same time slice, so their numbers would be the same. Make one Random object, put it in a field, and use it.

Comment: Can you make this question a whole lot more specific?  "Any help" covers a lot of things. What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: `RandomNumberMethod` This function doesn't mutate state or return a value....

Answer (score 0):

Write a method to check if the seahorses are facing the chicken. If they are, reverse their facing (do this just once).  Have them keep a certain distance away from the chicken. Use the distance formula with the origin of the chicken and the origin of each seahorse. If they are within that distance have them run straight in one direction until they hit a wall. When they hit the wall, have them turn 90 degrees right or left and do it again. Do this behavior until they are far enough away from the chicken. I would probably make the distance about 40% of the tank size (as a diameter) to ensure that they can find a corner to hide. Hopefully this helps, I haven't used Unity so I don't know specific methods to call. It should be simple object manipulation though. I would also add some effects to your vertical oscillation, perhaps increasing its frequency with a multiplier based on closeness to the chicken (lower oscilation distance, higher velocity). As for avoiding the running in the the chicken, You can set a minimum distance to the chicken (this one much closer) which will cause your seahorse to turn around if it gets too close, in which case it will resume its running to a wall and turning. All of this checking should run while the chicken leg exists.

Comment: Thanks for the help bob I have pretty much got it working now. And sorry for not making the original question more specific.